# I finished my first App, now what?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have finished my first App, and I previewed it without any problem. Now, how can I see it working from an smartphone? How can I send it to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can publish your app check: [App Maker Deployment](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment)

You can access your app from any browser mobile or not though the publication URL